# How to resolve the issue of Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-10-15-18-108.ec2.internal', ip: '10.15.18.108', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.94-89.73.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)

I have downgraded the Chrome in my local and want to have the same Driver version in Jenkins so how to fix the issue. Getting below error, while executing the Jenkins Job.

**Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.**

I have tried to update the Selenium dependency version

```
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>`I have updated to this version.
```